# Statistically significant majority

Tags: terminology

This is a terminological question. Does the phrase "significant majority" have a formal meaning in statistics? I have in mind something like 600 successes in 1000 trials, where the lower bound of the 99.99% confidence interval is greater than 50%. Or is it still just an informal expression meaning "lots more than half"?

---

EDIT

Assuming "significant majority" is just an informal expression, what's the most concise way to express the *prediction* that the number of successes will be such that the lower bound of the 99.99% confidence interval will be greater than 50%? I'm looking for a form of words.

Comment: Re EDIT: What's wrong with the words you have chosen to ask this?

Comment: I was hoping there was something a bit less wordy, but I'll stick with it if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning isn't formally fixed. For clear communication say explicitly that the majority is significantly larger than 1/2 (p<1e-8 or whatever, even better give the confidence interval). If you come across the term "significant majority" without any further explanation, the writer may or may not mean significant according to a statistical test, and I'd be rather annoyed because of ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you. I've made an edit to my original post, in view of your response.